# Deleting a button after clicking

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

i'm trying to remove/delete a start button from my scene, when i click on it, the button just becomes invisible but i still can click it and it restarts my scene... Any solutions anyone?

This is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if startButton.contains(location){

            restartScene()
        }

        if died == true {
            if restartButton.contains(location){
                restartScene()
            }
        }
    }

    startingGame()

}

func restartScene() {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.removeAllActions()
    died = false
    gameStarted = false
    score = 0
    createScene()
}

func createScene() {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    createGround()
    createBird1()
    createBackground()
    displayScoreLabel()
}
```

I already found that it had to do with this line:

```
 let location = touch.location(in: self)
```

I don't want this to be a location but a SKSpritenode, any solutions?
I'm still pretty new to swift so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Show the code for `restartScene`. The problem is in there I think.

Comment: @MaxPringle That is irrelevant as OP here is using SpriteKit, not UIKit.

Comment: @Sweeper  The code is in a next answer.. (did not know you could poste code in edits)

Comment: Please edit your question and delete the answer.

Comment: Are `startButton` and `restartButton` both `SKSpriteNode`s in your scene?

Comment: `func restartScene() {
        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.removeAllActions()
        died = false
        gameStarted = false
        score = 0
        createScene()
    }
    
    func createScene() {
        
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        createGround()
        createBird1()
        createBackground()
        displayScoreLabel()
    }`
@Sweeper

Comment: @DonMag yup they're both `SKSpritNode`s

Comment: OK - is your code correctly detecting the touches on the correct buttons? If so, have you tried `startButton.removeFromParent()` to *remove* it from the scene instead of just making it invisible?

Comment: @DonMag yes, it makes no differents...

Comment: If I find the solution, i will let you guys Know

Comment: @MathiasVerbessem - If you removed the node, and your code still detects it, then there is a problem with your code. Where is `startButton` coming from to begin with? Inside one of the `createScene()` functions? If so, it *looks* like you are re-creating the button right after removing it. If not, then where - and when - is it being created?

Comment: Hi Matthias- is this a button or (as is implied by your code) a custom view? I'm also wondering the reason you've overridden touchesBegan() rather than use a UITapGestureRecognizer. But I suggest you might want to try startButton.removeFromSuperview() on its own (I.e. Ignoring restartScene() for the time being) and see whether that works.

Comment: @Sparky i'm using SpriteKit and not UIKit so i don't have the option to `removeFromSuperview`